# Найти координаты точки, лежащей на биссектрисе угла, образованного двумя векторами, зная их координаты

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия, векторы

Даны 2 вектора а и b, исходящие из точки А, необходимо найти координаты точки В. Расстояние АВ вычисляю, АВ делит угол, образованный векторами пополам. Предполагаю перемещать координаты т.А для поиска В:

`В = (Ах + АВ * Соs Alpha; Аy + АВ * Sin Alpha)`

Затем строю вектор от А по Ох:

```
e = {100; 0}
```

Нахожу углы между а,е и b,e:

```
cos Betta = a * e / |a| * |e| ;   cos Gamma = a * e / |a| * |e|
```

И вот теперь для поиска Alpha, возможны два условия:

```
Alpha = (Betta - Gamma) / 2
```

Либо

```
Alpha = (Betta - Gamma) / 2 + min(Betta, Gamma)
```

Скажите, верны ли мои суждения? И какое условие должно быть для поиска Alpha?

Comment: почему вопрос о точках, а в итоге вы находите угол???

Answer (score 4):

> точки, лежащей на биссектрисе угла

Вы знаете сколько там точек, на биссектрисе? Миллионы!

---

Все гораздо проще. Приведите вектора `а` и `b` к единичной (или любой одинаковой) длине и сложите (векторно, конечно). Добавьте координаты их суммы к координатам точки `А` - это будет точка `B`. А `AB` - это диагональ ромба, построенного на приведенных векторах равной длины. Если в условии есть требование к длине `|AB|`, приведите получившийся вектор `AB` к этой длине.

Comment: Точно миллионы)) может миллионы+1?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ миллионы+2, кто больше?