# Нахождение угла и биссектрисы

Tags: javascript, canvas, математика, формулы, html5-canvas

Как сделать чтобы дорисововались лучи по точкам и рисовалась биссектриса угла. Можно просто формулу, функцию, но на javascript.

До:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">
 <canvas id="canv" style="position: absolute;"></canvas>
 <script>
  function checkDist(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
   return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2))
  }
  var canv = document.querySelector('#canv'),
  ctx = canv.getContext('2d'),
  w = canv.width = window.innerWidth,
  h = canv.height = window.innerHeight;
  var log = val=>console.log(val)
  var und;

  var dots = [],
  opts = {
   radius: 3
  };
  var deletedI;

  canv.onmousedown = e=>{
   if(e.which != 3) {
    if(dots.length < 3) {
     if(deletedI === undefined) {
      dots.push({x:e.x, y:e.y})
      canv.onmousemove = e=>{
       dots[dots.length-1]={x:e.x, y:e.y}
      }
     }else {
      dots.splice(deletedI,0,{x:e.x, y:e.y})
      canv.onmousemove = e=>{
       dots.splice(deletedI,1,{x:e.x, y:e.y})
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
  canv.onmouseup = ()=>{
   canv.onmousemove = und;
  }
  canv.oncontextmenu = e=>{
   canv.onmousemove = und;
   e.preventDefault()
   let arrForFilter = [];
   dots.forEach(cur=>{
    let dist = checkDist(e.x, e.y, cur.x, cur.y)
    arrForFilter.push(dist)
   })
   dots.forEach((cur, i)=>{
    let dist = checkDist(e.x, e.y, cur.x, cur.y)
    if(dist == Math.min.apply(Math,arrForFilter)) {dots.splice(i, 1);deletedI=i}
   })
   arrForFilter = [];
  }

  function anim() {
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h)
   dots.forEach((cur, i)=>{
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(cur.x, cur.y, opts.radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
   })
   if(dots.length == 2) {ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x,dots[0].y);ctx.lineTo(dots[1].x,dots[1].y);ctx.stroke()}
   if(dots.length == 3) {
    ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x,dots[0].y);
    ctx.lineTo(dots[1].x,dots[1].y);
    ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x,dots[0].y);
    ctx.lineTo(dots[2].x,dots[2].y);
        
        //лучше написать формулы тут

    ctx.stroke()
   }

   window.requestAnimationFrame(anim)
  }

  anim()
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Сделал, как все сказано, не работает.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">
 <canvas id="canv" style="position: absolute;"></canvas>
 <script>
  function vecLen(p) {
   return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p.x, 2) + Math.pow(p.y, 2))
  }
  function sumVec(p1,p2) {
   return {x:p1.x+p2.x, y:p1.y+p2.y}
  }
  function divVec(p1,p2) {
   return {x:p1.x/p2.x, y:p1.y/p2.y}
  }
  function getBiss(c,p1,p2) {
   let vecA = {x:p1.x/vecLen(p1), y:p1.y/vecLen(p1)},
   vecB = {x:p2.x/vecLen(p2), y:p2.y/vecLen(p2)},
   summVec = sumVec(vecA, vecB),
   c2 = sumVec(c, summVec)
   return c2
  }
  function checkDist(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
   return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2))
  }
  var canv = document.querySelector('#canv'),
  ctx = canv.getContext('2d'),
  w = canv.width = window.innerWidth,
  h = canv.height = window.innerHeight;
  var log = val=>console.log(val)
  var und;

  var dots = [],
  opts = {
   radius: 3
  };
  var deletedI;

  canv.onmousedown = e=>{
   if(e.which != 3) {
    if(dots.length < 3) {
     if(deletedI === undefined) {
      dots.push({x:e.x, y:e.y})
      canv.onmousemove = e=>{
       dots[dots.length-1]={x:e.x, y:e.y}
      }
     }else {
      dots.splice(deletedI,0,{x:e.x, y:e.y})
      canv.onmousemove = e=>{
       dots.splice(deletedI,1,{x:e.x, y:e.y})
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
  canv.onmouseup = ()=>{
   canv.onmousemove = und;
  }
  canv.oncontextmenu = e=>{
   canv.onmousemove = und;
   e.preventDefault()
   let arrForFilter = [];
   dots.forEach(cur=>{
    let dist = checkDist(e.x, e.y, cur.x, cur.y)
    arrForFilter.push(dist)
   })
   dots.forEach((cur, i)=>{
    let dist = checkDist(e.x, e.y, cur.x, cur.y)
    if(dist == Math.min.apply(Math,arrForFilter)) {dots.splice(i, 1);deletedI=i}
   })
   arrForFilter = [];
  }

  function anim() {
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h)
   dots.forEach((cur, i)=>{
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(cur.x, cur.y, opts.radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
   })
   if(dots.length == 2) {ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x,dots[0].y);ctx.lineTo(dots[1].x,dots[1].y);ctx.stroke()}
   if(dots.length == 3) {
    ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x,dots[0].y);
    ctx.lineTo(dots[1].x,dots[1].y);
    ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x,dots[0].y);
    ctx.lineTo(dots[2].x,dots[2].y);

    let angle1 = getBiss(dots[0],dots[1],dots[2]) 
    ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x,dots[0].y)
    ctx.lineTo(dots[0].x+angle1.x,dots[0].y+angle1.y)

    ctx.stroke()
   }

   window.requestAnimationFrame(anim)
  }

  anim()
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я в геометрии ноль, я столько вариантов пробовал, переписывал, неделю потратил впустую.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/875934/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: В этом то и второй вопрос все же делаю как там сказано

Comment: Я уже объяснил в ответе, в чем дело.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я в геометрии ноль

После такой фразы я обычно ставлю минус и закрываю закладку браузера. Если Вы - ноль, то станьте не нулем или не решайте такие задачи. Ну ладно.

---

В строке

```
let angle1 = getBiss(dots[0],dots[1],dots[2])
```

второй и третий параметры должны быть не точками на канвасе, а векторами, соответствующим двум Вашим отрезкам:

```
let angle1 = getBiss(dots[0], 
  { x: dots[1].x - dots[0].x, y: dots[1].y - dots[0].y },
  { x: dots[2].x - dots[0].x, y: dots[2].y - dots[0].y }
);
```

Исправления в местах, отмеченных `// !!! changes here:`:

```js
function vecLen(p) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p.x, 2) + Math.pow(p.y, 2))
}

function sumVec(p1, p2) {
  return {
    x: p1.x + p2.x,
    y: p1.y + p2.y
  };
}

function getBiss(c, p1, p2) {
  let len1 = vecLen(p1);
  let len2 = vecLen(p2);
  let vecA = {
    x: p1.x / len1,
    y: p1.y / len1
  };
  let vecB = {
    x: p2.x / len2,
    y: p2.y / len2
  };
  // !!! changes here:
  let result = sumVec(vecA, vecB);
  result.x *= (len1 + len2) / 2;
  result.y *= (len1 + len2) / 2;
  return result;
}

function checkDist(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
}
var canv = document.querySelector('#canv'),
  ctx = canv.getContext('2d'),
  w = canv.width = window.innerWidth - 20,
  h = canv.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
var log = val => console.log(val)
var und;

var dots = [],
  opts = {
    radius: 3
  };
var deletedI;

canv.onmousedown = e => {
  if (e.which != 3) {
    if (dots.length < 3) {
      if (deletedI === undefined) {
        dots.push({
          x: e.x,
          y: e.y
        })
        canv.onmousemove = e => {
          dots[dots.length - 1] = {
            x: e.x,
            y: e.y
          }
        }
      } else {
        dots.splice(deletedI, 0, {
          x: e.x,
          y: e.y
        })
        canv.onmousemove = e => {
          dots.splice(deletedI, 1, {
            x: e.x,
            y: e.y
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
canv.onmouseup = () => {
  canv.onmousemove = und;
}
canv.oncontextmenu = e => {
  canv.onmousemove = und;
  e.preventDefault()
  let arrForFilter = [];
  dots.forEach(cur => {
    let dist = checkDist(e.x, e.y, cur.x, cur.y)
    arrForFilter.push(dist)
  })
  dots.forEach((cur, i) => {
    let dist = checkDist(e.x, e.y, cur.x, cur.y)
    if (dist == Math.min.apply(Math, arrForFilter)) {
      dots.splice(i, 1);
      deletedI = i
    }
  })
  arrForFilter = [];
}

function anim() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)
  dots.forEach((cur, i) => {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(cur.x, cur.y, opts.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
  })
  if (dots.length == 2) {
    ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x, dots[0].y);
    ctx.lineTo(dots[1].x, dots[1].y);
    ctx.stroke()
  }
  if (dots.length == 3) {
    ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x, dots[0].y);
    ctx.lineTo(dots[1].x, dots[1].y);
    ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x, dots[0].y);
    ctx.lineTo(dots[2].x, dots[2].y);

    // !!! changes here:
    let angle1 = getBiss(dots[0], {
      x: dots[1].x - dots[0].x,
      y: dots[1].y - dots[0].y
    }, {
      x: dots[2].x - dots[0].x,
      y: dots[2].y - dots[0].y
    });

    ctx.moveTo(dots[0].x, dots[0].y)
    ctx.lineTo(dots[0].x + angle1.x, dots[0].y + angle1.y)

    ctx.stroke()
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(anim)
}

anim()
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" style="position:absolute;border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: А чем вектор в данном случае отличается от точки, мы не используем его направление и скорость, только местоположение, так же и у точки. Можно пару ссылок на введение, действия с векторами и так знаю

Comment: @Василий На введение куда? В школьный курс математики? Ваши `dots` - это куда щелкнули мышью. Компоненты вектора-отрезка - это разности соответствующих координат точек его конца и начала.

Comment: Что я делаю не так, что у меня не получается?

Comment: @Василий, что пишет в консоли разработчика?